# Child theme on style.min.css

Tags: child-theme

I am trying to create a child theme, and have come up with this.

```
    <?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION

if (!function_exists('chld_thm_cfg_parent_css')):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style('chld_thm_cfg_parent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'); 
        wp_enqueue_style('chld_thm_cfg_parent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.min.css'); 
    }
endif;
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css');

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

The purpose of this line `wp_enqueue_style('chld_thm_cfg_parent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.min.css');` is to get the style.min.css from the parent theme. However, when I check my live preview, it does not have the same font size that I set in style.min.css in the parent theme. Also, copying style.min.css into the child theme's folder does not seem to be wrong.

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the same identifier for style.css and style.min.css. Use a different identifier for each one.

Better: assuming that style.min.css is the minified version of style.css, enqueue only style.min.css.

```
if (!function_exists('chld_thm_cfg_parent_css')) {
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style('chld_thm_cfg_parent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.min.css'); 
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css');
```

Finally, clean the browser cache after changing the content of the style.min.css file. Otherwise the browser can use a old version stored in local cache.

To ensure your user will get the correct file, it is recommend to use the version parameter of `wp_enqueue_style` and change the version number each time you modify the style file:

```
if (!function_exists('chld_thm_cfg_parent_css')) {
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        //Fill with dependencies, if any
        $dependencies = array();
        //Change the version number after you change the content of the file
        //To ensure that browsers download it again and discard the one stored on cache
        $version = '1.0':
        wp_enqueue_style('chld_thm_cfg_parent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.min.css', $dependencies, $version ); 
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css');
```

Comment: Why did you approve such thing? It should be rejected, obviously.

Comment: I apologize the images didn't load for me due to slow connection. I thought they were part of the answer originally. That's why i immediately left a comment.